# Adobe Acrobat X Troubleshooting dropdown list color selection. Need One Click selection

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, dom-events, acrobat

I'm using dropbox boxes. I am using the following script to get different colors for different selections:

```
if (event.value=="Select") 
event.target.fillColor = color.white; 
else if (event.value=="Low Risk") 
event.target.fillColor = color.green;
else if (event.value=="Medium Risk") 
event.target.fillColor = color.yellow;  
else if (event.value=="High Risk") 
event.target.fillColor = color.red; 
else event.target.fillColor = color.white;
```

It is working fine EXCEPT, I have to click on the selection AGAIN before it will display the color. Any idea why? I really want a ONE CLICK SELECTION for the color. I have checked the "commit selected value immediately" box under the other options tab. I can only wonder if I am missing something in the Actions tab? Or maybe some additional Javascript that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Upon testing this, I found out that I had been in highlighted field mode. Once I changed it and unchecked "Highlight Existing Fields" the colors worked perfectly. I am leaving this here in case anyone is interested in knowing how to successful do this.